# Aura get boolean from parent to child

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning, aura-framework

I am very new to salesforce. The boolean value in the parent component will be updated by clikcing a button. That is done. Now I want to toggle a class in a child component based on the parent boolean value. So my question is how can I always read the parent boolean value from the child?

parent component

```
<aura:attribute name="isActive" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
```

child component

```
<div class="{!v.siActive ? 'bg-red' : ''}">
    ........
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:valueChange/documentation ?

Pass the parent attribute to child (in parent have something like `<c:myChild isActive="{!v.isActive}">`
and then in child define a handler function that will run on value change.

Actually there are few [patterns for parent-child communication](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/196857/pass-values-from-parent-to-child-component-on-click-lightning), pick what looks easiest/what's closest to what you already have

Comment: Thank you so much eyescream! +10 Hope this will update the child's class at runtime whenever the parent boolean is turned to true and false. I want this child to add and remove the class based on parent boolean changes.